# How to do a REST POST with Grafana AJAX panel?

Tags: ajax, rest, grafana

I have a SpringBoot API with a POST end-point.

Trying to make a call to end-point from Grafana [AJAX panel](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/ryantxu-ajax-panel/)

It seems to be hitting the end-point but error occurs complaining about missing body.

```
error: "Bad Request" message: "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity status: 400
```

But the request has indeed a body.

[image: Grafana AJAX POST request]

Have been looking for possible POST examples for hrs now but no joy, e.g.

https://community.grafana.com/t/using-ajax-plugin-to-make-rest-call/6674

Any tips or solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Asked this same question on Grafana support forum.

Turns out the plugin/panel in question does not support POST with body.

> Indeed, it looks like POST JSON data to backend is not currently supported. There seem to be two related issues here:
> https://github.com/ryantxu/ajax-panel/issues/48
> https://github.com/ryantxu/ajax-panel/issues/13
> You're welcome to share your thoughts there, it looks like this feature request has been added as a future enhancement but I am not sure when that work will be completed. In the meantime, you may need to forego using the AJAX Plugin.

So it's basically useless as my backend API end-point requires a body.

Answer (score 0):

try the new JSON API plugin
https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/?tab=changelog
or AjaxPanel plugin for more control

Comment: is there something wrong with the plugin ? I save an iframe panel and then when i return to dashboard screen it disappears

Comment: Ajax panel is very robust - if you use the  Display:Mode  Angular Template, wherein you can write js code to make ajax calls  (eg. using jQuery ajax etc).  This http mode i have not found it to be reliable.    Alternatively,  if you are on Grafana 8.2 and above try the new HTML-SVG plugin too. Its quite good.